# A single command to git pull a branch?

Tags: git

For example, I'm now in `develop` branch, and want to pull remote master to local master, what I do is:

```
$ git stash
$ git checkout master
$ git pull
$ git checkout develop
$ git merge master
```

Question 1: How to pull remote master to local master when I in `develop` branch?

Question 2: Is it possible to merge remote master to local develop in one command?
currently I use 4 commands

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Answer-1:** Your working procedure is ok for `question-1`.

```
$ git fetch
$ git stash
$ git checkout master
$ git pull origin master

$ git checkout develop
$ git stash apply
```

**Answer-2:** You can pull `origin/master` into your local `develop` branch directly.

```
$ git pull origin master
```

Comment: I don't think you need separate fetch for second case.

Comment: Yes. If we run `answer-1` commands first then second `fetch` is not needed. Actually, I tried to give the two answers independently here.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/difference-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch and https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull "git pull" will do fetch anyway, since "git fetch" does not change local state it is fine to run twice in a row, but really not necessary.

Comment: Agree with you. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

There are already other good answers to your question 2 (see sajib's). The short answer to question 1 is, "You can't".

However, If I can rephrase your question slightly to: "How can I pull remote master onto master while keeping develop checked out?" then you can use [`git worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) to your advantage. It gives you another working tree to do all the normal things you'd do with a working tree.

If you're on the develop branch and want to update master, for example:

```
git worktree add ../second-repo master
git -C ../second-repo merge origin master
```

Now master has been updated in your local repo.

To explain the above commands, `git worktree` will checkout master into another folder (`../second-repo`). The second command will execute `git merge origin master` only after virtually changing directories to the new worktree. Note that once you have a worktree set up, there's no need set it up again. You can just keep using the same worktree to update master.

Comment: I have never heard of `git worktree` before, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You're doing two merges there, one from `origin/master` to `master`, the second from `master` to `develop`, and you're doing them starting from a dirty worktree.

Merges need a worktree for conflict resolution: if `origin/master` and `master` both change a file, git has to do some work with the content, merging any that don't affect overlapping regions and possibly punting ones that do to you for your own inspection.

*Usually*, the sequence you show above can run without human intervention, but the important thing to stay aware of is that, at every step (and also the `git stash pop` you didn't show), it's very possible that somebody's going to have to look at a merge conflict and decide what was really meant.

Here's the example I usually give:  suppose you change

```
if ( tag == mark
  || tag == error ) {
```

to

```
if ( g->tag == mark 
  || g->tag == error ) {
```

and someone else changes it to

```
if ( tag == mark 
  || tag == error
  || tag == release ) {
```

what is git supposed to do?  I contend it does the only thing sanely possible: it punts, and asks you to decide what the result should look like.  Anyone familiar with C-family languages will be all but certain that the correct resolution is

```
if ( g->tag == mark 
  || g->tag == error
  || g->tag == release ) {
```

but arriving at that only when it really is the correct resolution is not within the generally accepted limits of reasonable expectation.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer-1:** fetch first from remote and then force branch...

```
$ git fetch
$ git branch -f master origin/master
```

- You can also just put `origin` without `/master` as it will default to it!
- You can "jump" to the forced branch by replacing `branch -f` with `checkout -B` like this...

  ```
    $ git fetch
    $ git checkout -B master origin/master
  ```

**Answer-2:** just pull (fetch & rebase/merge in one) defining the remote and branch...

```
$ git pull origin master
```